# Define switch for key=value

Tags: arguments, nim-lang

In nim, you can define a symbol via `-d:value` and test if it was defined with `defined(value)`. It is possible however to define a key and retrieve its value? I'm looking for something in the vein of `--colors:on` but user defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also looked for this and didn't find anything for my [nim-small-coreutils](https://github.com/def-/nim-small-coreutils). I ended up using environment variables as a hack and read them in a nonportable manner:

```
const colors = staticExec "echo \"$colors\""

when colors == "on":
  echo "It's on!"
else:
  echo "I guess it's off? The value is: ", colors
```

This takes the environment variable at compile time, so you can use it like this:

```
colors=on nim c example
```

or alternatively:

```
nim c --putEnv:colors=on c example
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting hack.